# Getting error trying to run tests using Jasmin with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, karma-jasmine

My test is simple, I Have a service manager that have 3 calls to retrieve json data in http get. For now I want to test one of the calls and see if it returns httpStatus of 200, simple, this is my code:

```
fdescribe('Manager Service', () => {

  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
      retrieveJsonAPIService,
      ManagerService
    ];
  });



  it('test getting json data', inject([ManagerService], (myService: ManagerService) => {

      spyOn(myService, "getJsonData").and.callFake(() => {
        return Observable.of({httpStatus: 200});
      });
    }));
});
```

this is it...but im getting this error:

> ✖ test getting json data
>
> ```
>   Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.3)
> TypeError: queueableFn.fn.call is not a function
> ```

does someone can explain to me what I needto fix here?